# SWF Flash Uploader invalidates JSESSIONID. Any idea to restore Session from server side or client side?

Tags: java, flash, session

I am using SWF Uploader to upload files. I am using java in server side.

Flash is invalidating Java Session automatically. SWF team didn't found any fix till now.

After some searches, i have found this [link](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/issues/detail?id=263), which discusses an idea to handle this problem in ASP.

> In basic PHP we pass the session id as a POST parameter and manually restore the session.
>
> In ASP.Net we also post the session id and use a Global.asax to catch the values
> before the session is restored and dynamically add the right cookies.

Like that do we have any option to restore the session in java?

I also gone through this [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155113/swfupload-and-java-session-is-lost) post. But i am not able to understand what they are telling exactly. Maybe its because, i am not sound enough in java session.

Especially `upload_url: "Controller?action=33&JSESSIONID=<%=request.getSession().getId()%>",` this line. What is he achieving with that line. What is `Controller` & `action=33`.

Any suggestions of restoring the session from client side or server side would be more appreciative!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read the linked SO question correctly, the problem is not invalidation of the session id, but the way the server treats the flash object: It is considered an additional client, not as part of the rest of the browser window.  Therefore, 2 separate sessions are created, causing the id to be different or null upon upload.

The solution is to manually look up the correct session id, or force the server to assign the correct id to a new session.  This is done by forwarding the jsessionid to Flash as a variable, and later adding it as a GET parameter to the HTTP upload request, so it can be retrieved on the server and you can use it to look up the correct session.

In the example, the author uses `Controller` as the name of the servlet, and `action=33` is probably used to invoke some method on it.  This is specific to this particular application, but not important for your solution.

What matters to you is the end of the string: `&jsessionid=<%=request.getSession().getId()%>`

This JSP code essentially adds the java session id to a variable containing the upload request URL.  You can do this in plain Java or any other language that has access to the correct session id - what matters is that it is transmitted to the Flash plugin first, **then** added to the upload request, **then** sent back to the server again, and **then** used to find or create the correct session id to process the upload with.

This is the code the author used to create a new session cookie:

```
if (request.getParameter("JSESSIONID")!=null) { 
    Cookie userCookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", request.getParameter("JSESSIONID"));    
    response.addCookie(userCookie); 
}
```