# Using Uploadify with Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, spring-security, uploadify

I am trying to use the Uploadify plugin with Spring MVC in order to upload a bunch of files. I am authenticated but my request keeps getting denied because when the flash based plugin makes a request, it is lacking the session id. There are bunch of examples on how to make this work with php.. I couldn't find any help for this case in the forum. Any ideas?

```
$('#uploadify_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '../js/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '/myproj/FileUploader/upload,    
    'cancelImg' : '../images/uploadify-cancel.png',   
    'auto'      : false,
    'multi'     : true,
    'scriptAccess' : 'always',
    'checkExisting': false,    
    'onComplete' : function(event,ID,fileObj,response,data) {
        alert("complete");
    },
    'onError'   : function(event,ID,fileObj,errorObj){
        alert("Error");
    }

  });
});

function handle(){
    $('#uploadify_upload').uploadifyUpload();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
<input id="uploadify_upload" name="uploadify_upload" type="file" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" onClick="handle()"/>
</div>
```

Comment: no code example? you should detail more your question.

Comment: thanks,added some code. My request does reach the server but fails at authentication level.

Answer (score 3):

You should change your script to append the JSESSIONID to the name of the Uploadify SWF, similar to the solution suggested on SO [for another SWF Uploader tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697162/swf-flash-uploader-invalidates-jsessionid-any-idea-to-restore-session-from-serve).

So, something like this should work (assuming the Javascript you note above is located in a JSP):

```
 $('#uploadify_upload').uploadify({
     'uploader'  : '../js/uploadify.swf?<%=request.getSession().getId()%>',
```

If you are not generating this Javascript from a JSP, you'll have to figure out how to get the JSESSIONID to the Javascript that is calling uploadify - you may need to introduce a parameter to the function that wraps uploadify, etc.